# why does gcc output a unrecognized binary file?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a simple c++ script called `test1.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Hola, moondo.\n";
    return 1;
}
```

Then I run it with:

```
$ g++ test1.cpp -o test.o
$ less test.o
"test.o" may be a binary file.  See it anyway?
```

Then it came out with unrecognized characters.

```
^?ELF^B^A^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^B^@>^@^A^@^@^@p^F@^@^@^@^@^@@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@<B8>^W^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@@^@8^@^H^@@^@^^^@ESC^@^F^@^@^@^E^@^@^@@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@@^@@^@^@^@^@^@@^@@^@^@^@^@^@<C0>^A^@^@^@^@^@^@<C0>^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^H^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^
```

It seems very simple, but I have no idea what's wrong with the process. Dose somebody know what happened?

Comment: Why would you expect the compiled code output by a compiler to be readable text?

Answer (score 2):

test.o is your actual executable, you are supposed to run it, not to edit it.

```
./test.o
```

Comment: And the filename of your executable should not end with `.o`